# Finding the length of a triangle given one side and the ratio the median and angle bisector cut the altitude.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, angle

A median BK, an angular bisector BE and an altitude AD are drawn in a triangle ABC. Find the
side AC if it is known that the line BK and BE divide the line segment AD into 3 equal parts and
if AB = 4cm. Find the length of AC.

[image]

Currently, I am able to work out that BD=2 by angle bisector theorem and that,since,sin BAD= 1/2; BAD=30 and angle ABC=60 but after that I'm unable to work it out further.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/czyAJEl

Comment: Pardon for the innaccuracy of the diagram.

Comment: Since $\overline{AD}$ is an altitude, $\angle BDA = \angle CDA = 90°$. Did you mean $\angle ABD$ perchance?

Comment: Yes, my mistake, I meant angle BAD

Comment: I think converting to a coordinate system works. Setting $B$ as the origin, $A$ is at $(2,2 \sqrt 3)$, and $M$ is at $(2,4/ \sqrt 3)$. Then $AK$ has slope $2/ \sqrt 3$. $K$ must be at $(x_1, 1/ \sqrt 3)$, since its y-coordinate must be halfway between the y-coordinate of $A$ and $C$, which is at $(2x_1,0)$. Now find the point on $AK$ that has that y-coordinate.  I suspect, though I haven't gone all the way through, that the triangle is obtuse.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca yes i'm certain the text is correct, but I also suspect the question is wrong

Comment: Gah, I didn't see a mistake until after the edit window. $K$ is at $(x_1, \sqrt 3)$, not $1/\sqrt 3$.

Comment: HINT. Point $C$ must be on the left of $D$. It turns out that $C$ is the midpoint of $BD$.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

I can help you with the construction, and you should be able to do the rest. Forget about the length of $AB$ for now.

1. Draw altitude $AH$ , draw the *baseline* (where points $B$ and $C$ should lie), and draw the *midline* (where point $K$ should lie). Mark points $X$ and $Y$, which divide $AH$ into 3 equal segments.
2. Draw circle $c$ with center $X$ and radius $XH$.
3. $X$ is on the bisector of $\widehat{ABC}$, so $AB$ should be tangent to circle $c$. Draw $AB$.
4. Draw $BY$. It meets the *midline* at $K$, the midpoint of $AC$.
5. Draw $AK$ and extend it to meet the *baseline* at $C$.

Now, can you do the rest?

Comment: Oh, this is *beautiful.* It's where my algebra comment leads, but without the algebra. I love seeing a good construction, and hopefully OP can follow it readily. Also a tip of the hat to Geogebra, I assume.

Comment: @EricSnyder Thanks a lot. You correctly noted that the triangle is obtuse. As for the image, I made it with AutoCAD.